# How to calculate NVM size of a java card applet CAP file

Tags: applet, javacard

Is there any one know how to get NVM (non-volatile memory) of java card applet file?

After researched on the Internet I can't find any tool or guide for this.

Comment: why did you tag this question as android?

Comment: Because I'm developing an Android project that use java card app

Comment: JCSystem has  the getAvailableMemory method. if you want to get the size of the persistent memory you can pass MEMORY_TYPE_PERSISTENT as parameter. You will get a short as return type

Comment: The problem is that java card app is supplied from third party and is only be run by putting on mobile device. I need to calculate NVM size of this java card app to register this card app. I don't know there is any tool to caculate persistent memory base on the input file like .cap file or not...

Comment: help me understand. Did you get the JavaCard Applet from a third party? Do you want to know the available persistent memory of the java card or I have misunderstood?

Comment: Did you get the JavaCard Applet from a third party?
>> yes.
Do you want to know the available persistent memory of the java card or I have misunderstood
>> yes. From What I know when registering java card app. Card Manager need following parameters:
1. Package AID
2. Applet AID
3. NVM size to reserve
I want to get the third parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can send GET DATA APDU command with P1=FF and P2=21, please refer to ETSI 102.226

APDU Command:
try this
80 CA FF 21 10

thanks

Answer (score 0):

send GET DATA command with Tag DF55 to the card manager (not to applet)